# Verify requests with box-python-sdk

Tags: python, python-requests, box

When I send requests to Box, I need to use the [verify](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) attribute. How can I set this attribute using [box-python-sdk](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk)?